# Calculating Randomized Singular Values has two main steps

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I am learning how calculating Randomized Singular value works from a text book.

They describe it in 3 steps. Let's say $X \in R^{m \times n}$ and we'd like to find a randomized svd for it.

1. We believe it can be captured by a low rank space with dim r, which we call Z. Sample $P \in R^{n, r}$
   $$
   \begin{equation}
   Z = X P
   \end{equation}
   $$
2. calculate $QR$ decomposition for $Z$.
3. Use Q matrix for change of basis (i.e. calculate $Y = Q^T X$) then calculate the svd for Y. Then for each $U_y$ as a eigenvalue of Y, use Q to lift it back to a $m$ dimensional vector and use. thus
   $$
   \begin{equation}
   U_x = Q U_Y
   \end{equation}
   $$

My question is that, since Q and $Q U_Y$ are from same dimension and both orthonormal matrixes, why don't we just stop at step two and won't use Q as the $U_X$.

I am mostly looking for a intuitive answer rather than exact proof.

Comment: What are $R^{m\times n}$ and $R^{m,r}$? (I'm asking because nothing I can guess makes $Z=XP$ come out as well-defined.)

Comment: @joriki I corrected the set containing P to $R^{n \times r}$ instead of what it was before. $R^{n \times r}$  is set of all real valued matrix with n rows and r columns.

The intuition is that r is way smaller than n so Z = XP is m * r matrix and is substantially narrower than X.